# how to fetch data from database where selected spinner value and field value in database table matches?

Tags: android

In the database I have one table called mechanic having fields:

name  |  address  | phoneno  | city | speciality

I want to use two spinners one is for specialty and other is for city and I want to fetch those mechanics from mechanic table where specialty selected on specialty spinner and city selected on city spinner matches the city and specialty fields of mechanic table in database how can I achieve this functionality in my app?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **WHERE** clause.

You can try following query.

```
SELECT * FROM mechanic WHERE specialty = 'yourSelectedSpecialty' AND city = 'yourSelectedCity'
```

Please note, you need to use single quotes around your values.

Comment: can you tell me how to get the values from both spinners so that i can use in where clause??

Comment: You can implement OnItemSelectedListener in your activity. Have a look at http://www.javatpoint.com/android-sqlite-example-with-spinner